# Sending keyboard events to other windows from wxwidget app in linux

Tags: linux, wxwidgets, x11

I'm writing a linux application using C++ and wxWidgets.
From my application, I need to send keyboard events to the window that currently has the focus (not belonging to my application!).

My questions are:

1. How can I find out what window has the focus?
2. How can I send a keyboard event to a window not belonging to my application?

Thanks
Daniele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `XGetInputFocus(3)`.
2. X11 does not care about "applications". There are only windows. It's enough to have a window ID (`Window` is the Xlib data type). Use whatever method of sending events works. There are two methods I know of: `XSendEvent(3)` and `XTestFakeKeyEvent(3)`. The former method does not work with some programs that chose to ignore events coming from `XSendEvent`. The latter one requires the `XTest` extension, which is present in most, but not all, modern servers.
3. Note that `InputFocus` is a valid window designator for `XSendEvent`, and `XTestFakeKeyEvent` is delivered to the window that has the focus anyway, so you probably don't need to call `XGetInputFocus` at all.

Comment: So, are you suggesting I cannot do that inside WX, but I must use Xlib?

Comment: WX doesn't seem to provide user-accessible wrappers around these functions, so yes, you will have to use them directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you use 2.9, you can use [wxUIActionSimulator](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_u_i_action_simulator.html). It is intended to work with other windows of the same (wxWidgets) application but AFAICS it should actually work with the windows of other applications when using X11 too (however I didn't test it myself).